# Example of a divisor of a function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and on page 97 Fulton defines the divisor of the rational function $z\in k(C)$:

[image]

I'm looking for an example of a divisor like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your curve to be $\mathbb{P}^1$. And take any rational function $z(x) :=p(x)/q(x)$; where $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Then the zeroes of $z(x)$ are exactly the zeroes of the polynomial $p$ and the poles are exactly at the zeroes of $q$.

Depending on the degree of $z$, defined as $deg(p) - deg(q)$ the behaviour at $\infty$ changes.

If you are looking for a particular example then take $z(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$. This has a zero at $x=0$ and a pole at $x=1$. This is a degree $0$ rational function whose divisor is $div(z) = 1\cdot[0] - 1\cdot[1]$, which is also of degree 0.

Comment: 1) You have to assume $p$ and $q$ relatively prime. 2) Your rational function $\frac{x}{1-x}$ has degree 1, not 0 (it is an automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$).

Comment: @Georges: but the degree of any principal divisor is $0$! This is not the same notion of degree as the degree of a rational function as a map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: of course the degree **of the divisor**  of a rational function is zero but the degree **of the rational function** $\frac p q$ ($p,q$ relatively prime) is the maximum of the degrees of $p$ and $q$. And this is exactly the same as the degree of the corresponding map $\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^1$. It is also the degree of the corresponding extension field $[\mathbb C(x):\mathbb C(\frac pq)]$. What is your definition of the degree of a rational function?

Comment: The definition of degree of a rational function can be found in Exercise 6 of the  Miscellaneous Exercises to Chapter 13 in Artin's Algebra (page 535) or on page 243 of Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, Exercise 11 to section 4.5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for your remarks. I have a question, why $ord_{x=0}(f)=ord_{x=1}(f)=1$? Because $x$ and $x-1$ are irreducibles?

Comment: @Georges: I see, I misread ayberk's answer slightly.

Comment: @user42912: the order of $z(x)= \frac{x}{1-x}$ at $x=1$ is $-1$, not $1$.This is because you can write $z(x)=(-x)\cdot  (x-1)^{-1}$ and $-x$ is invertible in a neighbourhood of $x=1$, so it has order $0$ while $(x-1)^{-1}$ has order $-1$ (remember that the order of a product is the sum of the orders of the factors).